# About Lubin Tate extensions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4473761/about-lubin-tate-extensions

I know this is a very low-level question because it is about a probable typo and a definition. But I asked this question on MSE, and I didn't receive any response.

This is from the $6^{th}$ section of the last chapter of the book class field theory by childress:

(Page 201): "We shall use the polynomials that give rise to Lubin-Tate formal group laws to construct certain totally ramified abelian extensions of a local field $K$. Let $q =$ #$\mathbb{F}_K$ and, as before, let $\mathcal{F}_{\pi_K}$ denote the set of all power series $f (X) ∈ \mathcal{O}_K [[X]]$ such that $f (X) \cong \pi _K X (\mod X^2)$ and $f (X) \cong X^q (\mod \pi_K )$. Suppose $f(X)\in \mathcal{F}_{\pi_K}$ is a monic polynomial of degree $q$. Then $$f (X) = X^q + \pi_K (a_{q−1}X^{q−1} +· · ·+a_2X^2) + \pi_K X,$$ where $a_j ∈ \mathcal{O}_K$. For a positive integer $m$, define recursively
$$f ^{(1)}(X) = f (X), f ^{(2)}(X) = f ( f (X)), . . . , f ^{(m)}(X) = f ( f ^{(m−1)}(X)).$$
By (i ) and (ii ) of Corollary 5.3, we have
$$f (X) = [\pi_K ]_f (X), \space\space \space and \space f ^{(m)}(X) = [\pi_K^m ]_f (X).$$
**It follows that if $\lambda \in \mathcal{P}_f$ , (the Lubin-Tate module), then
$$f ^{(m)}(X) = \pi_K^m \space ·_f \lambda."$$**

> (The **major** question) Look at the bold lines above. I can not see how an arbitrary $\lambda$ played this role? This $\lambda$ seems to be chosen arbitrarily. Does it have a typo? Should it written as "$f ^{(m)}(\lambda) = \pi_K^m \space ·_f \lambda$"? Then I think everything is correct and compatible.

---

(Page 200) About corollary 5.3 mentioned above: From the corollary 5.3, the power series $[a]_f (X)$ allows us to define a formal $\mathcal{O}_K$ -module structure when combined with the formal group law $F_f$. And after that, the book defined two operations $+_f$ and $._f$ to make $\mathcal{P}_{\Omega}$ an $\mathcal{O}_K$-module (which the author denote $\mathcal{P}_f$). Especially the operation $._f$ defined as follow:

- For $a \in \mathcal{O}_K$ and $x\in \mathcal{P}_{\Omega}$, the series $[a]_f (x)$ converges to an element of $\mathcal{P}_{\Omega}$, which we denote $a \space ·_f x$.

(Pages 182 & 183) Some of notations defined at the beginning of the chapter:

- $\mathcal{P}_K = \{x \in K : v_K (x) > 0\} = \pi_K\mathcal{O}_K$,
- $\Omega$ a complete, algebraically closed extension of $\hat{K}_{ur}$

> (The **minor** question on the definition of $\mathcal{P}_{\Omega}$) It seems the author forgot to define $\mathcal{P}_{\Omega}$, but I think it should be something very similar to $\mathcal{P}_K$. But I can not write its definition, because I think we don't have a uniformizer in $\Omega$. How can we define a valution on $\Omega$ in the absence of uniformizers?

Comment: I agree that this is a typo and $X$ should be $\lambda$.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Thank you for your comment, I have so much doubt about it.

Comment: You don’t use a uniformizer to define the valuation on a finite extension field $L$, you use the formula $V(\alpha)=\frac1{[L:K]}v_K\bigl(\text{Norm}^L_K(\alpha)\bigr)$. This extends $v_K$ to $L$, and so extends to the direct limit $\Omega$.

Comment: Dear Prof. @Lubin , **(I)** I can easily see that your comment explains that the valuation on $K$ (i.e. $v_K$) extends to the direct limit $K_{ur}$. **(II**) Then by completing with respect to the valuation $v_{K_{ur}}$ we obtain $\hat{K}_{ur}$ (and obviously we have the valuation $v_{\hat{K}_{ur}}$ on $\hat{K}_{ur}$, which is defined in a natural way in the completion process). **(III)** Then again your comment explains that the valuation on $\hat{K}_{ur}$ (i.e. $v_{\hat{K}_{ur}}$) extends to the direct limit $\Omega$. Is the above argument correct?

Comment: Right now, to me, I think the problem is that I can not remember the procedure of passing to the $\Omega$ (a complete, algebraically closed extension of $K_{ur}$). 


Which one gives us $\Omega$? The algebraic closure of the completion of $K_{ur}$? Or the compleition of the algebraic closure of $K_{ur}$?

Comment: I searched, and I think "the algebraic closure of the completion of $K_{ur}$ gives us $\Omega$ (a complete, algebraically closed extension of $K_{ur}$). (And for a general valued field "the algebraic closure of the completion of $K$ is not necessarily equal to "the completion of the algebraic closure of $K$", and it is equal to "the algebraic closure of the completion of the algebraic closure of $K$.)

Comment: Perhaps my last comment is wrong.

Comment: I’m sorry, but I guess I don’t know what $\Omega$ is. I was assuming that it was some infinite algebraic extension of the base $K$. If you’re talking about some complete field, then you have to use the fact that the extension of the valuation on the uncompleted thing to the completion is unique.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks for your patience and your kindness. $\Omega$ is a complete, algebraically closed extension of $\hat{K}_{ur}$, and I think I understand everything after your comments, and to me, everything is solved. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: And $\hat{K}_{ur}$ is the completion of $K_{ur}$